# Importing CSV - Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, relationship

I have a csv file that looks like this:

|  | food | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | orange | fruit |
| 1 | banana | fruit |
| 2 | eggplant | vegetable |
| 3 | cucumber | fruit |
| 4 | carrot | vegetable |
| 5 | tomato | fruit |
| 6 | tomato | vegetable |
| 7 | cucumber | vegetable |
| 8 | onion | vegetable |
| 9 | cauliflower | vegetable |

How do I graph this so that the food nodes are unique, but the fruit categories are not lost for foods that belong to more than one category?

So far I have used this code:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT UniqueFood FOR (f:food) REQUIRE f.foodName IS UNIQUE

LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///food.csv' AS row
WITH toInteger(row[0]) AS foodId, row[1] AS foodName, row[2] AS foodType
MERGE (f:food {foodName: foodName})
SET f.foodName = foodName, f.foodType = foodType
RETURN f


LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///food.csv' AS row
WITH toInteger(row[0]) AS foodId, row[1] AS foodName, row[2] AS foodType
MERGE (t:foodType {foodType: foodType})
SET t.foodType = foodType
RETURN t

MATCH (f:food)
MATCH (t:foodType) WHERE f.foodType = t.foodType
CREATE (f)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(t)
```

but for cucumber and tomato, it only assigns these a relationship with one category and not both.

Also, how do I drop the header row? When I add 'WITH HEADERS' to the code above, I get an error: "Type mismatch: map key must be given as String, but was Integer (line 2, column 20 (offset: 72))
"WITH toInteger(row[0]) AS foodId, row[1] AS foodName, row[2] AS foodType" "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore the header row, you can just skip it:

```
LOAD CSV ... AS row
WITH row SKIP 1
...
```

But you don't need to do that. You should keep the `WITH HEADERS` option, delete the `WITH toInteger(row[0]) AS foodId, row[1] AS foodName, row[2] AS foodType` clause, and then use `row.food`, and `row.category` throughout the rest of the query instead of `foodName` and `foodType`. [*Aside: The first header in your header row is an empty string, so it can't be used as the name of a `row` property. However, since your queries don't actually use that column, this does not affect you.]*

In the rest of this answer, I will assume you use your headers:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///food.csv' AS row
MERGE (f:Food {name: row.food})
SET f.type = CASE WHEN f.type IS NULL THEN [row.category] ELSE f.type + row.category END
RETURN f
```

The above query will add all the categories for a `Food` to a list of categories.

You should not keep the category names in the `Food` node AND also have relationships to those categories as separate nodes. Just do one or the other.

If you want to create relationships to unique `FoodType` nodes instead:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///food.csv' AS row
MERGE (f:Food {name: row.food})
MERGE (t:FoodType {type: row.category})
MERGE (f)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(t)
```